# Getting outline of polygon as GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, convex-hull

I have geojson data that draws shapes similar to the following:

[image]

I wanted to know if there are any operations that can give me the geojson which represents the outline of these shapes represented by the red lines in the following image:

[image]

The coordinates do not have to match exactly what is represented by the red lines I only need the coordinates to wrap the outside boundaries of the shape.

Comment: What software are you using? It is better to convert geojson into shp etc then  transform and get the transformed geojson..

Comment: Sounds like you want a convex hull.

Comment: I'm a programmer, and I am looking for a known formula to apply to many of these kind of shapes.

Comment: turf js has code for a convex hull from a set of points (vertices of a polygon) geoJSON example https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/turf/

Comment: Here are code samples in multiple languages, pick your poison: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain

Comment: If you use GDAL you make it execute Spatialite SQL. An example with ogrinfo: `ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "select ST_ConvexHull(geometry) FROM OGRGeoJSON" test.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Turf.js can create convex hull from geojsons. https://turfjs.org/docs/#convex

Answer (score 0):

You can try also:
https://geoman.io/studio - which bases on the leaflet-draw plugin, having an option to direct saving these files as a .geojson extension.